# Trig question - should be easy but it's probably lacking information

Tags: trigonometry

A person I know had this question on his 9th grade school test:

> You are standing on the edge of a cliff. Looking down from the cliff you see a river that is $3$ miles from the base of the cliff. Directly above the river you can see an airplane that is flying $7$ miles above the river. From your perspective of the cliff, what is the angle of elevation and what is the angle of depression?

As far as I can say, there is insufficient data: we know that the altitude of the plane is $7$ miles (the "base" of the triangle) and the "height" of the triangle is $3$. If we sketch it, we basically have two right triangles. but we do not know what is the height of the cliff. That to me seems like a key piece of information. Am I correct? This would make the question not suitable for a test.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Any height of the cliff is possible, thus any possible angle.

Comment: @JohnDoe thank you.

Comment: while any height of cliff may be possible there just are not very many cliffs in the world that are more than a couple of hundred feet.  Making this distance trivial compared to the 7 miles that the plane is above you.  At the very least, you can find an upper bound for this angle, assuming the height of the cliff is small.

Comment: @DougM  a 2640 foot cliff would be half a mile. Making the angle of depression about 9 degrees (not negligible) and the angle of inclination 65.2  degrees vs 66.8 degrees for being on the ground.  IMO although not very significant is not  justification for a bad question.

Comment: @fleablood It is possible that this story takes place at the top of El Capitan.  And I agree it is a bad question.  But, my best answer would be "less than 66.8 degrees."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I should probably have written my comment as an answer. For the sake of completeness, since this problem is solved, I will write it here.*

Yes, you are correct. Any height of the cliff is possible, thus any possible angle.